# How to setup ResultSetMapping for association / foreign key [was Why are associations returned by native queries always null]

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

**See edit at end for updated question about ResultSetMapping**

I have two entities defined (Item and ItemType), one of which has a ManyToOne association to the other. I have quite a few native queries due to some complexity of generating finding the right items. These queries always return all columns of the first entity (SELECT items.* ...).

I've found that my associations are always null on the first item and I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. Any help would be appreciated.

Entities:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="items")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ItemRepository")
 */
class Item {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="account_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $accountId;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ItemType")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $itemType;

    // ..snip.. //

}
```

ItemType

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="item_types")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ItemTypeRepository")
 */
class ItemType {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="account_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $accountId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128)
     */
    private $name;

    // ..snip.. //

}
```

The query is generated by the method getItem of my ItemRepository class. This is a bit long but boils down to a `SELECT items.* FROM items ...` query run via `getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);`

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

/**
 * ItemRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class ItemRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @var ItemTypeRepository
     */
    protected $itemTypes;

    /**
     * @var ItemValueRepository
     */
    protected $itemValues;

    /**
     * @var FieldRepository
     */
    protected $fields;

    /**
     * Called by service bindings in services.yml instead of __construct, which is needed by
     * Doctrine.
     */
    public function initService(LoggerInterface $logger,
                                ItemTypeRepository $itemTypes,
                                ItemValueRepository $itemValues,
                                FieldRepository $fields)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->itemTypes = $itemTypes;
        $this->itemValues = $itemValues;
        $this->fields = $fields;
    }

    /**
     * Get items for an account via itemId
     *
     * @param integer $accountId a user's account id
     * @param $itemId unique ID for an Item
     * @return Item_model
     */
    public function getItem($accountId, $itemId, $restrictedUserOwnerItemType, $restrictedUserOwnerItemId)
    {
        $this->logger->debug(__METHOD__.'::params::'.json_encode(['accountId' => $accountId, 'itemId' => $itemId,
                             'restrictedUserOwnerItemType' => $restrictedUserOwnerItemType, 'restrictedUserOwnerItemId' => $restrictedUserOwnerItemId]));
        if(!$accountId || !$itemId || !is_numeric($restrictedUserOwnerItemType) || !is_numeric($restrictedUserOwnerItemId)) 
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('getItem requires accountId, itemId, restrictedUserOwnerItemType and restrictedUserOwnerItemId');

        /*
        $query = $this->itemsModel->builder();
        $result = $query->where('account_id', '=', $accountId)
                        ->where('id', '=', $itemId)
                        ->first();
        */

        $sql = "SELECT items.*, ".
        "item_types.id AS item_type_id, ".
        "item_types.account_id AS item_type_account_id, ".
        "item_types.name AS item_type_name, ".
        "item_types.plural_name AS item_type_name, ".
        "item_types.label AS item_type_label, ".
        "item_types.plural_label AS item_type_plural_label, ".
        "item_types.are_users AS item_type_are_users, ".
        "item_types.own_users AS item_type_own_users ".
        "FROM items ".
        "JOIN item_types ON item_types.id = items.item_type_id ";

        $isRestrictedUser = $restrictedUserOwnerItemType != 0 || $restrictedUserOwnerItemId != 0;
        if($isRestrictedUser)
        {
            // Limit to items that are visible to restricted users
            $sql .= <<<SQL


      WHERE item_types.visible_to_restricted_users = 1 

SQL;

            // Limit to items that contain a relationship field pointed at the same owner item type,
            // with the same item ID. For instance, limit items to those that have a Clients relationship
            // field with "Acme Co." client selected as the client.
            $sql .= <<<SQL

AND items.id IN ( /* Where Item Belongs to Same Owner */
      SELECT item_id 
      FROM item_values 
      JOIN fields ON fields.id = item_values.field_id
      JOIN items ON items.id = item_values.item_id AND item_values.ver = items.ver
      JOIN item_types ON item_types.id = items.item_type_id
      WHERE item_values.value = ?
        AND fields.field_type = "Relationship"
        AND fields.field_item_type_id = ?)

SQL;
            $params[] = $restrictedUserOwnerItemId;     // Example: 3  -- CLIENT ID
            $params[] = $restrictedUserOwnerItemType;   // Example: 10 -- CLIENTS

            $sql .= "AND ";
        } else {
            $sql .= "WHERE ";
        }

        $sql .= "items.account_id = ? AND items.id = ? ";
        $params[] = $accountId;
        $params[] = $itemId;

        // Get raw records
        $rsm = $this->standardResultSetMapping();
        // $this->logger->debug($sql);
        // $this->logger->debug(print_r($params, true));
        echo $sql;
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
        $query->setParameters($params);

        // Wake up the entities
        $result = array();
        foreach($query->getResult() as $row) {
            $row->initServiceEntity($this->logger, $this, $this->itemValues, $this->fields);
            $result[] = $row;
        }

        if(!$result || count($result) == 0)
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Item could not be located for Item #".$itemId.". You may not have permission to view this item or it may not exist.");
        else
        {
            return $result[0];
        }
    }

    private function standardResultSetMapping()
    {
        $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
        //                    Class,                    Table
        $rsm->addEntityResult('\AppBundle\Entity\Item', 'items');
        $rsm->addEntityResult('\AppBundle\Entity\ItemType', 'item_types');
        //                   Table,   Column,           Property
        $rsm->addFieldResult('items', 'id',             'id');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('items', 'account_id',     'accountId');
        //$rsm->addFieldResult('items', 'item_type_id',   'itemTypeId');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('items', 'field_count',    'fieldCount');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('items', 'ver',            'ver');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('items', 'title',          'title');
        $rsm->addMetaResult('items', 'item_type_id',    'item_type_id', true);

        $rsm->addFieldResult('item_types', 'item_type_id',          'id');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('item_types', 'item_type_name',        'name');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('item_types', 'item_type_plural_name', 'pluralName');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('item_types', 'item_type_label',       'label');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('item_types', 'item_type_plural_label','pluralLabel');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('item_types', 'item_type_are_users',   'areUsers');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('item_types', 'item_type_own_users',   'ownUsers');

        return $rsm;
    }

}
```

The Item entity is returned but always has a null itemType:

```
Item {#548 ▼
  -id: 23
  -accountId: 1
  -itemType: null
  -fieldCount: 4
  -ver: 1451940837
  -title: "New Item"
  #fields: []
  #itemValues: []
  #cacheValues: []
  #logger: Logger {#268 ▶}
  #itemsRepository: ItemRepository {#349 ▶}
  #itemValuesRepository: ItemValueRepository {#416 ▶}
  #fieldsRepository: FieldRepository {#338 ▶}
  #loaded: true
  #changeCount: 0
}
```

item_types data

```
id  account_id  name  plural_name label plural_label  are_users own_users
31  1           task  tasks       Task  Tasks         1         0
```

items data

```
id  account_id  item_type_id  field_count ver         title
23  1           31            4           1451940837  New Item
```

***Edit*** I've narrowed this down to the ResultSetMapping configuration, I think. Updated code above. The result now returns two distinct objects, but does not wire them up (the Item's itemType is still null):

```
object(AppBundle\Entity\Item)[560]
  private 'id' => int 23
  private 'accountId' => int 1
  private 'itemType' => null
  private 'fieldCount' => int 4
  private 'ver' => int 1451940837
  private 'title' => string 'New Item' (length=8)
  protected 'fields' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'itemValues' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'cacheValues' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'logger' => null
  protected 'itemsRepository' => null
  protected 'itemValuesRepository' => null
  protected 'fieldsRepository' => null
  protected 'loaded' => boolean false
  protected 'changeCount' => int 0
object(AppBundle\Entity\ItemType)[507]
  private 'id' => int 31
  private 'accountId' => int 1
  private 'name' => string 'task' (length=4)
  private 'pluralName' => string 'tasks' (length=5)
  private 'label' => string 'Task' (length=4)
  private 'pluralLabel' => string 'Tasks' (length=5)
  private 'areUsers' => boolean true
  private 'ownUsers' => boolean false
```

So the question is now basically:

How do I setup ResultSetMapping so that it will return an Entity with all joined associations intact?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `EXTRA_LAZY` on the `$itemType` on your `Item` entity?

Comment: Same result, I had added that in an attempt to get it to work. Just removed that so it's a bit clearer, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: did you try a @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ItemType", fetch="EAGER") ?

Comment: fetch="EAGER" did not have any effect

Comment: The problem is you want to have a array ( array ( $itemObj, $itemObjType ) ) ?? but you can't if have this if your $itemObjType containe a id who repeat it, doctrine find more fast to do array( $itemObj, $itemObjType,$itemObj ) then array( array($itemObj,$itemObjType), array($itemObj,$itemObjSameType) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doctrine's [documentation on Native SQL](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) has some good insights, and it makes it pretty clear what your error is.  The short answer to your existing post is that you should be using `addJoinedEntityResult()` instead of `addEntityResult()` for your **ItemType** entity.

The [documentation for Entity Results](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#entity-results) states:

> An entity result describes an entity type that appears as a root element in the transformed result.

This means that if you add two entity results in the same mapping, you will get the results you are currently seeing - both **Item** and **ItemType** returned as two distinct objects.  However, you know that the two are related, so a [Joined Entity Result](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#joined-entity-results) makes more sense:

> A joined entity result describes an entity type that appears as a joined relationship element in the transformed result, attached to a (root) entity result.

To directly fix your code as is, you would need to change

```
 $rsm->addEntityResult('\AppBundle\Entity\ItemType', 'item_types');
```

to this:

```
$rsm->addJoinedEntityResult(
    '\AppBundle\Entity\ItemType',
    'item_types',
    'items',
    'itemType'
);
```

The format is `addJoinedEntityResult($class, $alias, $parentAlias, $relation)`, so you can see the 3rd and 4th parameters added that point to the parent alias and the field in your **Item** class that points to **ItemType**.

That all being said, I think you are making this too complicated and can greatly simplify your code by using the [ResultSetMappingBuilder](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#resultsetmappingbuilder).  This can automatically map the fields to their SQL column equivalent, and then if you ever change the name of the field or the names of the columns in the database, you won't have to dig through all of your code to update in your mappings.

So instead of calling your complex `standardResultSetMapping()` function, you could simply do this instead:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->_em);
$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('AppBundle\Entity\Item', 'items');
$rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('AppBundle\Entity\ItemType', 'item_types', 'items', 'itemType',
    ['id' => 'item_type_id', 
     'account_id' => 'item_type_id', 
     'name' => 'item_type_name',
     'plural_name' => 'item_type_plural_name',
     'label' => 'item_type_label',
     'plural_label' => 'item_type_plural_label',
     'are_users' => 'item_type_are_users',
     'own_users' => 'item_type_own_users']
);
```

With that, you eliminate redundant code, make it less prone to errors, easier to test, and automatically handle updates to your entities and database.  The second call shows that you can still pass an array of renamed columns as well.

Comment: This was pretty much the answer, however because all tables (by default) have the same id column at a minimum I had to map that using the 4th parameter to addJuinedEntityFromClassMetadata. In actual fact, all of the fields pretty much have to be renamed since many overlap and I prefer consistency. I updated your answer's last code snippet with the final version that works with my code above.

Comment: Glad that worked.  I approved your edit with a few small tweaks to give more information about the 5th parameter for renaming columns.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are selecting only from table items (items.*) doctrine uses lazy loading, and did't load from any data from joined tables.

Put in your select all data you want to get i.e.:

```
SELECT items.*, item_types.* ...
```

Comment: If that's the case how can lazy loading ever work correctly? In fact I want lazy loading to work since not all requests need every nested object (and there are many in the real, complete entity graph). Is accessing the column via $result[0]->getItemType() not correct?

Comment: Although this isn't how I would like to solve it, I did try adding this and it does not work. The field is still null.

Comment: Code in the question updated with my attempt to make this work. I added the relevant entityResult and fields to the ResultSetMapping and put the method that generates that in the question as well.